# Web Page not accepting text sent from vba

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

```
Sub login()

Dim objie As InternetExplorer

    Set objie = New InternetExplorer

    objie.Visible = True

    objie.navigate "https://kite.zerodha.com/"

    Do While objie.Busy = True Or objie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    objie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "abcdefgh"

    objie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Value = "abcdefgh"
    objie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click


End Sub
```

The website I am trying to automate is not accepting text sent from vba. So I tried sendkeys method and it worked. But I want to run the Internet explorer in background. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: That's odd. I can step through with F8 and all three login actions work for me.

Comment: User Id and password is displayed on webpage page. But after pressing login button, I am getting the error "user id should be minimum of six characters" which is not the case when I manually type with keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/) in this case. It is far more reliable. After install, VBE > Tools > References, add reference to selenium type library.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://kite.zerodha.com/"
    With d
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementByCss("[type=text]").SendKeys "abcdef"
        .FindElementByCss("[type=password]").SendKeys "123456"
        .FindElementByCss("[type=submit]").Click
        Stop '<== Delete me later
        '.Quit '<==Uncomment me later
    End With
End Sub
```

---

With IE you can add `.Focus` and use `.innerText` as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub login()
    Dim objie As InternetExplorer
    Set objie = New InternetExplorer
    objie.Visible = False
    objie.navigate "https://kite.zerodha.com/"

    Do While objie.Busy = True Or objie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    With objie.document
        .querySelector("[type=text]").Focus
        .querySelector("[type=text]").innerText = "abcdef"
        .querySelector("[type=password]").Focus
        .querySelector("[type=password]").innerText = "123456"
        .querySelector("[type=submit]").Click
    End With
End Sub
```